# Implementing SCORM package viewer in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, scorm

Does anybody have experience in implementing the SCORM package viewer in ASP.NET application can help me. I am new to this topic. My requirement is like, admin will import the SCORM package contents into application, so that, user will take the assessment. I have Reload SCORM Player, can read scorm content, need same kind of library for asp.net.
Thanks,
Senthil.